# QrCoder Asp.Net - How to remove noise?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, bitmap, asp.net-core-mvc, qr-code

Right now I'm creating my QR-Code using QrCoder from Asp.Net. You can see my code below:
**SvgQrCode:**

```
    public void UpdateText(string value)
    {
        using (var qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator())
        {
            using (var qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(value, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q))
            {
                using (var qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData))
                {
                    using (var bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(1, Color.Black, Color.White, false))
                    {
                        Image.FromData(bitmap);
                    }
                    Text = value;
    }   }   }   }
```

**Xml:**

```
   <Image Source="{Binding Element.ImageSource}"
          RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
          RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
          Width="{Binding Element.Width}"
          Height="{Binding Element.Height}"
          Stretch="Uniform">
```

**What happens:**
The generated QR-Code has some light noise that you can see here in the screenshot on the left side(left side Gray8, right side BlackWhite):
[image]

**What I tried:**
I changed in the method `Decode` the `Pixelformats` from `Gray8` to `BlackWhite`. The result is the screenshot above (qr code on the right side).

```
 internal static BitmapSource Decode(string value, int? pixelWidth, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)
 {
        // ..some code..
        var grey = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bitmap, PixelFormats.Gray8, BitmapPalettes.Gray256, 1.0);
        return grey;
 }
```

Another thing that I tried is changing `qrCode.GetGraphic(1)` to something higher like `qrCode.GetGraphic(10)`, which increases the `pixels per module`. But this is not a clean way to fix the problem, because the noise is just getting realy small(so you can hardly see it anymore) and the pixel per module are getting increased.
**My Problem:** I'm using the method decode for qr codes, bar codes and images. So If I would add an image it would be black and white. Of course I can use an if-statement and check what if its an image or or qr/bar-code. But why is `PixelFormats.Gray8` creating noise? Why is it not clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I overlooked those lines and didnt realize that .jpeg was choosen as format:

```
public void FromData(Bitmap bitmap)
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
     bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     //...
```